# PHP variables not working in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some trouble getting my variables to work inside a MySQL query. I have done this before but for some reason its not working. I am probably missing something but can't figure it out can anyone help me?

My Code

```
$cat = "Fashion"; 

$article = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category = $cat ORDER BY views");

if($article->results(){
echo 'success!'; 
}
else{
echo 'no';
}
```

I should be getting 'Success' echoed out but instead i get 'no'; Fashion is a category in my db so no idea why this is not working for me.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the variable in single quotes? `WHERE category = '$cat'` etc.

Comment: `views"` missing a bracket and semi-colon => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and a colon `echo 'no':` instead of a semi-colon. `if($article->results(){` missing a bracket. So, don't ask yourself why your code is failing.

Comment: You get `'no'` because that's what you programmed the system to show you when there's an error.  You might also try getting the actual error from the database object, I'm sure it's trying to tell you why the query failed.  (Though the code shown will fail for several reasons, so I suspect this isn't even the code you're using.)  Ultimately, use prepared statements with query parameters instead of directly concatenating values and this syntax/quoting error becomes a moot point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$article = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category = $cat ORDER BY views"
```

This line is missing the close parenthesis and semi-colon.

Also, the variable *should* be enclosed in single quotes.

Change that line to:

```
$article = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category = '$cat' ORDER BY views");
```

---

Your `if` statement is also syntactically wrong. Close parenthesis missing:

```
if($article->results(){
```

Colon instead of semi-colon:

```
echo 'no':
```

This whole section should look like:

```
if($article->results()) {
    echo 'success!'; 
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

With a bit of cleanup and [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), it could look as simple as:

```
echo $article->results() ? "success!" : "no";
```

Comment: you missed quite a few things ;-)

Comment: Halfway through a draft @Fred-ii-... this will be longer than my thesis...

Comment: Thanks man, It was just the single quotes i was missing. And sorry for the missing semi-colons i just wrote it up rough on here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I hope you realize this is vulnerable to SQL injection unless you have full control of the input variables.

Secondly, the variable should probably have single quotes around it, i.e.

```
$article = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category = '$cat' ORDER BY views");
```

Note I also added the missing `);` from the end of that line.

Finally, you seem to be missing another `)` on your if statement.

Comment: you missed something also ;-)

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice the `:`. Good spot @Fred-ii-. It's a wonder this code managed to output anything at all.

Comment: Yeah, that colon is suspicious because it would demand that the SHIFT key be pressed, and are both on the same key. Hard to say if the OP's just not trying to thrown everyone a curve ball ;-)

Comment: My Code was just a rough example of what i actually have. Alot of the mistakes are just me trying to type to fast and failing. All sorted now i was just missing the semi-colons, ha! I have done this a dozen times but completely missed that!